# How to integrate Payfort payment gateway in React Js?

Tags: reactjs, payfort

I want to integrate Payfort payment gateway in my React JS App. Didn't find any documentation for this.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

officially no support for javascript

find the official repo here [payfort repo](https://github.com/payfort)